# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages for laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I use 5.7v Laravel and 7.2.1v PHP and composer last version, but when I like to create new project these errors appeared:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for league/flysystem 1.0.47 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.47]. 
    - league/flysystem 1.0.47 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
Problem 2  
    - league/flysystem 1.0.47 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.  
    - laravel/framework v5.7.9 requires league/flysystem ^1.0.8 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.47]. 0 
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.7.9 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.9].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php-7\php.ini You can also run php --ini inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.`
```

Comment: have you tried `composer install` to install the dependencies for the project?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

First of all, stop the XAMPP/Wamp and then kindly remove the starting semicolon ( `;` ) from your **xampp\php\php.ini** the following code.

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

or in windows with IIS

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

And then restart your XAMPP/Wamp.

---

**NOTE:** For Windows, you can find the file in the ***C:\xampp\php\php.ini***-Folder (Windows) or in the etc-Folder (within the xampp-Folder).

Comment: In my case, i had both installed php and xampp and in my path, i pointed at `c/php/`as the PHP interpreter. In `c:/php/php.ini`, it was `;extension=fileinfo` whereas in `c:/xampp/php/php.ini` it was `extension=fileinfo`. I did two changes,

1. Deleted `c:/php/`
2. Changed my path to php to point to `c:/xampp/php/`

The problem is now resolved

Comment: I got this error on a cpanel. How can I fix it?

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks mr. Sarvaiya, this saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 25):

The problem seems to be what the error message says - your system is missing *fileinfo* PHP extension.
Since you're on Windows, open *C:\php-7\php.ini* file, search for the following line, and remove the beginning `;` if exists:

```
extension=fileinfo
```

or in windows with IIS

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Comment: Windows is so weird when it comes to what is enabled by default.

Answer (score 5):

Just **uncomment** `extension=fileinfo` in `php.ini` it worked for me even without xampp

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just uncomment `extension=fileinfo` in `php.ini` then it works

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had both installed PHP and XAMPP and in my path, i pointed at `C:/php/`as the PHP interpreter. In `C:/php/php.ini`, it was `;extension=fileinfo` whereas in `C:/xampp/php/php.ini` it was `extension=fileinfo`. I did two changes,

1. Deleted `C:/php/`
2. Changed my path to PHP to point to `c:/xampp/php/`

**The problem is now resolved**

Answer (score 0):

Simple soultion, just **delete php 7.4.11 folder** from C drive.

update php location from **C:\php 7.4.11** to **C:\xampp\php** in path variable under environmental variable

Answer (score -4):

in my case i am using window machine ...my league/flysystem is missing ..
type this command in cmd on project Dir..
composer require league/flysystem

for mine case  its work...