# Laravel create project 1

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I create a laravel project, it puts me the error message that you see in the photo, you will notice that it has no .env file present in the list at the top of the image, it is a project that I try to create ... composer is well installed, I have php 7.3.8. I do not understand what he asks me ..
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtW4c.png)

Comment: in your `php.ini` uncomment `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`. Then restart server. I hope this will work

Comment: install/enable the missing extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734707/your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set-of-packages-for-la

Comment: In future, please post the error within a code block here (copy from your screen and paste using the `{}` icon in the edit window here).  Posting images of messages is not generally recommended

Answer (score 1):

One of your packages requires a library to be installed / working within your PHP instance.  In this case it is looking for fileinfo.  To get this working:

From your php folder on your server, open your php.ini

Find and un-comment the following line (remove the `;` before the line):

```
 extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Restart your server.

If this is your first run or install, you may have other errors, but the error message is usually pretty helpful in this case.  Google on the error line of what's missing and it will generally give you a good clue as to how to fix the install issues :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `fileinfo` extension. So you need to enable the extension.

- Find the PHP installation folder, look in the `ext` folder and make sure it contains the file `php_fileinfo.dll`.
- In the PHP installation folder, look for the `php.ini` file and open it with a text editor.
- Search for `php_fileinfo.dll` and you may find a commented out section. If you do then uncomment it (by removing the leading ; character)
- If you don’t then add a line for it: `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`
- Restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing fileinfo extention thats why i suggest you to install NodeJs and that might be fix your problem.

Before create a project you have to install 3 Things:

1. NodeJS from [https://nodejs.org/en/]
2. Composer [https://getcomposer.org/]
3. Gitbash [ https://git-scm.com/downloads]